# phonegap : How to upload docx,pdf files from ios app

Tags: javascript, ios, angularjs, cordova, cordova-plugins

How can I upload docx,pdf files from iOS app? Is there any plugin for that ? Tried camera plugin and html5 fileupload, but it opens to photos only.

Comment: there are a lot of "file picker" or "file chooser" plugins. The html input type file will allow you to pick files on most android devices and iOS 9 devices, but then you should send the files using AJAX instead of using file-transfer plugin

Answer (score 0):

try to use fileTransfer plugin.
https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file-transfer

Comment: I am using this plugin for file transfer. The problem is , I can't select docx,pdf  files in iOS using camera plugin or file upload. It opens to 'photos' only

Comment: The camera plugin is not for documents.  Use the `file` and `file-transfer` plugins to locate the documents.

Comment: file transfer plugin is for uploading the documents, but before that we need to get a path to it. I would like to know how we can retrieve the path from storage.

Comment: Is there any plugin to retrieve directory listing that contains docx,pdf files in storage of iOS?

Comment: use 'file' plugin to retrieve directory listing and file-transfer to upload. if you want to preview docx,pdf files, try to rewrite this plugin http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/fileOpener2/